# Ruby- sort array based on string in index

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, sorting, indexing

I've been staring at sort forums forever now and I officially accept that i do not understand whats going on.

I have an array called "people" with multiple index's
each array index looks like this

```
("Steven", "32", "Detroit", "single")

("Fred", "19", "Boston", "married")

("Jason", "25", "san_fransisco" "single")
```

I want to sort these index's by city (3rd entry of an index)

I've looked at so many different websites and i'm not following this at all. Can someone help me out with an answer and briefly explain whats going on? Is this even possible using an array?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you have an array of arrays (which is trivial to sort), or something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
people = [
  ["Steven", "32", "Detroit", "single"],
  ["Fred", "19", "Boston", "married"],
  ["Jason", "25", "san_fransisco", "single"],
]

people.sort_by{|p| p[2]}
```

Comment: Ugh. I can't believe it was that easy. Thank you!!